# what dose 'being a machine gun attack on a whole field of straw men' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The problem with this neat triad is that, while a tirade against horoscopy might be perfectly agreeable to most everyone (**being a machine gun attack on a whole field of straw men**  — who reads horoscopes save for feeble amusement?), assertions on life and climate are on another plane entirely.

[Rex Murphy: Governor General appoints herself umpire of questions of faith and science](http://nationalpost.com/opinion/rex-murphy-governor-general-places-herself-as-umpire-of-questions-of-faith-science)

I googled and have understood the fallacy of a straw man, but still don't get the meaning of the bold phrase in the sentence above. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a metaphor.  Attacks on "horoscopy" (by which I assume they mean *astrology*, but that's not important) are usually pointless since it's such an easy target to criticize, analogous to *shooting down a field of stationary targets with a machine gun.*

A common English idiom is ["like shooting fish in a barrel"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/like-shooting-fish-in-a-barrel), meaning something is *ridiculously easy*.  The author tried to be clever by combining this metaphor with the "straw man" fallacy.